# Counting and summing unique data in several columns then matching it with another unique data

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, format

This is an addition question of [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38006549/3397819). I was not able to find a way to figure it out for hours nor also to find an idea from online search.

Suppose I have the following data (the actual data can be thousands or millions) in Excel sheet (Table 1):

```
Name    Entry   No. ID  Expense 1   Expense 2
A       1       A1      14          5
B       2       B4      12          7
B       2       B5      20          8
C       3       C0      19          7
D       4       -       0           0
A       1       A1      11          6
A       1       A2      20          5
E       5       -       0           0
F       6       -       0           0
C       3       C0      15          5
B       2       B5      20          4
B       2       B5      16          3
B       2       B5      12          7
B       2       B6      18          8
A       1       A1      10          1
A       1       A1      14          7
A       1       A2      10          2
B       2       B3      13          7
B       2       B3      14          1
B       2       B3      11          4
```

The character (-) in column No. ID above can be also a number 0 or a blank cell.

I want to format the above data as follow (Table 2)

```
Name    Entry   No. ID  Number of ID    Sum of Expense 1    Sum of Expense 2
A       1       A1      2               49                  19
A       1       A2      2               30                  7
B       2       B3      4               38                  12
B       2       B4      4               12                  7
B       2       B5      4               68                  22
B       2       B6      4               18                  8
C       3       C0      1               34                  12
D       4       -       0               0                   0
E       5       -       0               0                   0
F       6       -       0               0                   0
```

Column Number of ID means A has 2 IDs (A1 and A2), B has 4 IDs (B1, B2, B3, and B4), C has 1 ID (C0), and D, E, and F have no ID. Column Sum of Expense 1 and 2 are the sum of all expense for each no. ID.

The best I can get by using Pivot Table is like this

[image: ![enter image description here]

How does one perform a task like Table 2 in MS Excel? If possible a VBA script of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code after modifications works when running it from the same Workbook (doesn't matter which Worksheet).

Added an array to dynamic add number **Sum of Expense** types.

This code covers the logic needed to convert you table's data just like you wanted.

```
Sub OrganizeTable()

Dim TableArray()                        As Variant
Dim i, j, k, i_tmp, LastRow             As Long
Dim Sum_Count                           As Integer
Dim SheetData, SheetResult              As Excel.Worksheet
Dim StringTemp                          As String
Dim LongMin, LongMax                    As Long
Dim SumExpense()                        As Long
Dim Number_of_ID                        As Long
Dim Number_of_Expense_Type              As Integer

' Number_of_Expense_Type = number of expense type you have in your
Number_of_Expense_Type = InputBox("Enter number of expense type ", "Expense Type counter")

Set SheetData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = SheetData.Cells(SheetData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
Set SheetResult = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Erase TableArray

ReDim TableArray(1 To LastRow - 1, 1 To 3 + Number_of_Expense_Type) ' create array with exact number of Project names
ReDim SumExpense(1 To Number_of_Expense_Type)
i = 2
' insert all table's data into multi-dimensional array (easier and faster to manipulate later)
While SheetData.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    For j = 1 To 3 + Number_of_Expense_Type
        TableArray(i - 1, j) = SheetData.Cells(i, j)
    Next
    i = i + 1
Wend


LongMin = LBound(TableArray())
LongMax = UBound(TableArray())

' this loop is for sorting the array according to Name, and then No. ID
For i = LongMin To LongMax - 1
    For j = i + 1 To LongMax
        ' 1st rule: check for Name Value in Column A
        If TableArray(i, 1) > TableArray(j, 1) Then
            For k = 1 To 3 + Number_of_Expense_Type
                StringTemp = TableArray(i, k)
                TableArray(i, k) = TableArray(j, k)
                TableArray(j, k) = StringTemp
            Next
        End If
        ' 2nd rule: check for No. ID in Column c
        If TableArray(i, 1) = TableArray(j, 1) And TableArray(i, 3) > TableArray(j, 3) Then
            For k = 1 To 3 + Number_of_Expense_Type
                StringTemp = TableArray(i, k)
                TableArray(i, k) = TableArray(j, k)
                TableArray(j, k) = StringTemp
            Next
        End If

    Next
Next


i = 1
j = 2 ' this is the Row number where the sorted table will start
k = 1 ' this is the Column number where the sorted table will start
While i <= LongMax
    SheetResult.Cells(j, k) = TableArray(i, 1)
    SheetResult.Cells(j, k + 1) = TableArray(i, 2)
    SheetResult.Cells(j, k + 2) = TableArray(i, 3)

    For Sum_Count = 1 To Number_of_Expense_Type
        SumExpense(Sum_Count) = TableArray(i, 4 + Sum_Count - 1)
    Next

    ' this IF and WHILE loop are for accumulating the Sum Expense 1 and Sum Expense 2 for the same ID type
    If i + 1 <= LongMax Then
        While TableArray(i, 3) = TableArray(i + 1, 3) And TableArray(i, 1) = TableArray(i + 1, 1)

            For Sum_Count = 1 To Number_of_Expense_Type
                SumExpense(Sum_Count) = SumExpense(Sum_Count) + Val(TableArray(i + 1, 4 + Sum_Count - 1))
            Next

            i = i + 1
        Wend
    End If

    ' this IF and WHILE loop are for counting how many Num of ID you have per Name
    Number_of_ID = 0
    If TableArray(i, 3) <> "-" Then
        Number_of_ID = 1
        For i_tmp = 1 To LongMax - 1
            While Cells(j, k) = TableArray(i_tmp + 1, 1) And TableArray(i_tmp, 1) = TableArray(i_tmp + 1, 1) And TableArray(i_tmp, 3) <> TableArray(i_tmp + 1, 3)
                Number_of_ID = Number_of_ID + 1
                i_tmp = i_tmp + 1
            Wend
        Next
    Else
        Number_of_ID = 0
    End If

    SheetResult.Cells(j, k + 3) = Number_of_ID

    For Sum_Count = 1 To Number_of_Expense_Type
        SheetResult.Cells(j, k + 4 + Sum_Count - 1) = SumExpense(Sum_Count)
        SumExpense(Sum_Count) = 0
    Next

    Number_of_ID = 0
    j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
Wend

' writing down the headers for you table
SheetResult.Cells(1, k) = "Name"
SheetResult.Cells(1, k + 1) = "Entry"
SheetResult.Cells(1, k + 2) = "No. ID"
SheetResult.Cells(1, k + 3) = "Number of ID"

For Sum_Count = 1 To Number_of_Expense_Type
    SheetResult.Cells(1, k + 4 + Sum_Count - 1) = "Sum of Expense " & Sum_Count
Next

Set SheetData = Nothing
Set SheetResult = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I have checked your code and it perfectly works. Many thanks. One more question, let say I want to add Sum of Expense 3, 4, 5, and so on. What kind of variables or syntax should I change or add? Could you make it one for me where the arrays can be  easily manipulated? I've tried to change your code to do that, but it doesn't work perfectly

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 , is Sum of Expense 3, 4 , 5 are the total final numbe you want to have ? or dynamic ? where are you going to keep the data ? on the columns to the right od Sum Expense 1, 2 ? cause it will require shifting the existing parameters a little .

Comment: 3,4,5, and so on are also the sum of number like Expense 1 and 2. If possible the column of expense can be added easily, for example let say 10 to 15 column Sum of Expense. Let's also say I put my data in Sheet 1 and the result will be displayed in the Sheet 2. Could you add your answer as my request, please? Thank you so much...

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 , check the modified code above, you can now run it from different worksheets. Also, you get an input box, just enter the number of "Sum of Expense" you have in your table.

Comment: I'm really sorry for bothering you again, but I want to know how if the columns: Name, Entry, and  No. ID are also dynamic number like Expense? Let's say this static columns with names: Name, Entry,  No. ID, Date of Birth, Phone Number, etc. I tried to modify your code by adding syntax: `Number_of_Columns = InputBox("Enter number of static columns ", "Static Columns Counter")`, but then I'm confused. Could you help me out?

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 the code i wrote works weel for what you requested in your original post. However, if you keep adding new things that you need, then the code will need modifications (maybe major ones), and also might not be ideal. When starting to code you need to have the whole picture, it's not ideal all the time to add little pieces of code for every new need that you have. Try to think of all the things you need, and post a new question with the latest code you have.

Answer (score 1):

Below code might help:

**Assumptions:**

**1.** Your data is in `ActiveSheet`
**2.** Result will be displayed in the `Sheet2`

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim dict1 As Object, dict2 As Object
    Dim c1 As Variant, c2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, targetRow As Long, count As Long
    Dim targetWS As Worksheet

    Set targetWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'get last row with data
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'assign unique values in Column A (Name) to dict1
    c1 = Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    For i = 1 To UBound(c1, 1)
        dict1(c1(i, 1)) = 1
    Next i

    'assign unique values in Column C (No. Id) to dict2        
    c2 = Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
    For i = 1 To UBound(c2, 1)
        dict2(c2(i, 1)) = 1
    Next i

    'write headers in Sheet2
    targetWS.Cells(1, 1) = "Name"
    targetWS.Cells(1, 2) = "Entry"
    targetWS.Cells(1, 3) = "No. Id"
    targetWS.Cells(1, 4) = "Number of ID"
    targetWS.Cells(1, 5) = "Sum of Expense 1"
    targetWS.Cells(1, 6) = "Sum of Expense 2"

    'fill data in table        
    targetRow = 2    '-->targetRow will keep the counter for new row in Sheeet2

    'loop through unique values of Name through dict1
    For Each k1 In dict1.Keys
        count = 0
        'loop through unique No. ID through dict2 to match values in dict1 and dict2
        For Each k2 In dict2.Keys
            If k2 Like k1 & "*" Then    '-->match values of dict1 and dict2
                count = count + 1
                'fill data in table if match found
                targetWS.Cells(targetRow, 1) = k1
                targetWS.Cells(targetRow, 3) = k2
                targetWS.Cells(targetRow, 4) = dict2(k2)
                targetWS.Cells(targetRow, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("C2:C" & lastRow), k2, Range("D2:D" & lastRow))
                targetWS.Cells(targetRow, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("C2:C" & lastRow), k2, Range("E2:E" & lastRow))
                targetRow = targetRow + 1
            End If
        Next k2

       'fill data if no match found
        If count = 0 Then
            targetWS.Cells(targetRow, 1) = k1
            targetWS.Cells(targetRow, 3) = "-"
            targetWS.Cells(targetRow, 5) = 0
            targetWS.Cells(targetRow, 6) = 0
            targetRow = targetRow + 1
        End If
    Next k1

    'get values for Entry and Number of ID
    For i = 2 To targetWS.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        targetWS.Cells(i, 2) = Range("A:A").Find(What:=targetWS.Cells(i, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Offset(0, 1).Value
        targetWS.Cells(i, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(targetWS.Range("A1:A" & lastRow), targetWS.Cells(i, 1))
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Note:** Above code will not display data in ascending order like `A1-A2-B3-B4-B5-B6-C0` instead data will be displayed in the order of appearance like `A1-A2-B4-B5-B6-B3-C0`

See image for reference:
[image]

Comment: Gimme time to consider both of your answers. Thanks. (+2)

Answer (score 0):

You can have VBA to copy the pivot table data and paste it as normal table.